# How do I send files with netcat using find?

Tags: bash, find, netcat

I am trying to send a large number of json files via netcat, but I can't seem to get the find -exec combination right.
I am in the directory with the json files and have tried the following:

```
find -iname "*.json" -type f -exec netcat 127.0.0.1 6002 < {} \;
```

whichs returns `-bash: {}: No such file or directory`

```
find -iname "*.json" -type f -exec cat {} | netcat 127.0.0.1 6002 \;
```

whichs returns `find: missing argument to '-exec'`

Comment: Also, I wasn't sure if this was the right stack to ask on. Should this maybe be on SuperUser?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out an answer with help from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389706/254118:

```
find -iname "*.json" -type f -exec sh -c 'cat $1 | netcat 127.0.0.1 6002' sh {} ';'
```